# How to Handle null parameter Error On Add-Migrations in Razorpages tutorial

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations, razor-pages

I have a fresh install of VS 2016 15.3 and the Dot Net Core 2.0 SDK

I am following the [tutorial for Dot Net Core 2.0 Razorpages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model)
and have reached the "Model" step.  There I created the single entity and dbcontext per instructions and added the connection string code to the places indicated in the tutorial.  Best I can tell, my project is exactly like the tutorial.

When I got to the step to go into PM and run `Add-Migration Initial`,
 I got an "argument null exception: parameter error indicating it couldn't find the configuration string".  The tutorial did not call for any arguments to the `Add-Migration` command nor does it provide any guidance on this issue.

How can I proceed with this tutorial.? There does not seem to be a way to get to the author of the tutorial.

My connection string defined in appsettings is:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "**MovieContext**": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Movie-1;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

The Startup.cs has the DbContext service is looking for that connection string:

```
services.AddDbContext<MovieContext>(options =>                
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("**MovieContext**")));
```

Here is the output when I try running `Add-Migration Initial`:

```
PM> Add-Migration Initial
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\RRR\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
**System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: connectionString**
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1 sqlServerOptionsAction)
   at RazorPagesMovie.Startup.<ConfigureServices>b__4_0(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) in C:\Users\RRR\Source\Repos\RazorPagesMovie\RazorPagesMovie\Startup.cs:line 29
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0`1.<AddDbContext>b__0(IServiceProvider p, DbContextOptionsBuilder b)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.DbContextOptionsFactory[TContext](IServiceProvider applicationServiceProvider, Action`2 optionsAction)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass5_0`1.<AddCoreServices>b__0(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__5`1.<AddCoreServices>b__5_1(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetServices[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.FindContextTypes()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.FindContextType(String name)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: connectionString
```

Answer (score 2):

Found error - dyslexic typing and poor eyesight:
  error was in the appsettings.json file
  I had added the Connection string piece incorrectly:

```
  {
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    },
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "MovieContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Movie-1;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    }
  }
}
```

(making it a part of Logging instead of its own first-level entry as in the correct version:)

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "MovieContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Movie-1;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    }
}
```